# Why am I getting an `EmptyStackException` from my code?

Tags: java, exception, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

```
public class ShuntingYard
{
    public String infix2postfix(String infix)
    {
        Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
        String[] tokens = infix.split(" ");

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        Integer plus = Integer.getInteger("+", 1);
        Integer minus =Integer.getInteger("-", 1);
        Integer multiply = Integer.getInteger("*", 2);
        Integer divide = Integer.getInteger("/", 2);
        Integer exponent = Integer.getInteger("^", 3);

        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
        {
            if (tokens[i].matches("[0-9]"))
            {
                output.append(tokens[i] + " ");
            }
            else if (tokens[i].equals("+") || tokens[i].equals("-") || tokens[i].equals("*") || tokens[i].equals("/") 
                    || tokens[i].equals("^"))
            {
                int a = plus.intValue();
                int b = minus.intValue();
                int c = multiply.intValue();
                int d = divide.intValue();
                int e = exponent.intValue();

                if (s.isEmpty() == false && tokens[i].valueOf(a).compareTo(s.peek()) >= 0|| 
                s.isEmpty() == false && tokens[i].valueOf(b).compareTo(s.peek()) >= 0 || 
                s.isEmpty() == false && tokens[i].valueOf(c).compareTo(s.peek()) >= 0 || 
                s.isEmpty() == false && tokens[i].valueOf(d).compareTo(s.peek()) >= 0 ||
                s.isEmpty() == false && tokens[i].valueOf(e).compareTo(s.peek()) >= 0)
                {
                    output.append(s.peek() + " ");
                    s.pop();
                }
                s.push(tokens[i]);
            }
            else if (tokens[i].equals("("))
            {
                s.push(tokens[i]);
            }
            else if(tokens[i].equals(")"))
            {
                while (!(s.peek().equals("(")))
                {
                    output.append(s.pop());
                }
                if (s.isEmpty() == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error: mismatching parentheses");
                }
                s.pop();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; s.isEmpty() == false; i++)
        {
            if(s.peek().equals("(") || s.peek().equals(")"))
            {
                System.out.println("Error: mismatching parentheses");
            }
            output.append(s.pop());
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
}
```

.

```
@Test
public void infix2postfixTest()
{

 assertEquals("3 4 5 6 - 7 * 8 / + - 9 *", s.infix2postfix("3 * ( 4 + ( 5 - 6 ) * 7 / 8 ) - 9"));
}
```

When I run the ShuntingYard test, the second code posted, I get a `EmptyStackException` that points to this line:

```
while (!(s.peek().equals("(")))
```

but the logic makes sense to me, I'm saying if the token is a ")", then while the top of the stack isn't a "(" append the top of the stack to the output and remove it from the stack. Am I missing something here?

Here is my stack peek method:

```
public T peek()
{
    if (isEmpty() == true)
    {
        throw new java.util.EmptyStackException();
    }

    return stack.get(stack.size()-1);
}
```

Comment: Never compare `String` values with !=, use `s.peek().equals("(")` instead.

Comment: Also there are no "No exception" error, you should add the complete exception stacktrace to your question. `Stack.peek` can throw a `EmptyStackException` if you try to peek in an empty stack.

Comment: yes i did implement a empty stack exception to my peek, and the error does mention it

Comment: You don't need to implement it, it is already implemented. Or do you mean that you've implemented your own Stack class ?

Comment: yes my own stack class

Comment: Really ? So please provide the complete error trace + your implementation of the Stack class.

Comment: How am i getting an empty stack exception though, since that is the error I am receiving

Comment: I can't tell you if you don't provide the code of your `Stack` class and the complete error message. But I really doubt that you implemented your own generic `Stack` class

Comment: lol i did, i'll put it up.

Answer (score 0):

You have been popping and peeking the [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) without checking if it is empty first. Peeking or popping an empty stack generates the [`EmptyStackException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EmptyStackException.html) you have been getting. As you pointed out, the `Stack` class does check [`isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#isEmpty()) within [`peek()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#peep()), but it only does so to generate the `EmptyStackException`. It is your responsibility as the caller of `peek()` to check `isEmpty()` yourself first! If you don't do this then you have created an impossible situation for the `Stack`- it can't show you the result of a peek if there is nothing to peek from the empty `Stack`!

You should replace:

```
else if(tokens[i].equals(")"))
{
    while (!(s.peek().equals("(")))
    {
        output.append(s.pop());
    }
    if (s.isEmpty() == true)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: mismatching parentheses");
    }
    s.pop();
}
```

with something similar to:

```
else if(tokens[i].equals(")"))
{
    while(!s.isEmpty())
    {
        if(s.peek().equals("("))
        {
            s.pop();
            if(s.isEmpty())//we just popped so the while check no longer applies
            {
                System.out.println("Error: mismatching parentheses");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            output.append(s.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

The fix can be implemented differently than my example of course. but the walkaway is that you must check `isEmpty()` before calling either `peek()` or `pop()`.

As an additional side note, I wanted to point out that your original code for printing out the mismatching parentheses error is unreachable. The if statement executes once the while statement ends, and when the while statement ends you are guaranteed to that the s `Stack` is non-empty! That guarantee makes the subsequent pop call safe, but also means the error message never executes. I fixed that additional bug in my example, but I wanted to explain it in more detail since otherwise you might not notice.